# Java Swing: Components automatically change position when a certain component updates

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I made a Java program and part of the program's function is to track the user's mouse X and Y coordinates.

The tracking works nicely but there's a small problem that bothers me.

When I move my mouse around the screen, the other components automatically change position.

Here's a MRE(Minimal Reproducible Example):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Test {
    static Timer t;
    static JLabel label1;
    static InnerTest inner;
    static int mouseX;
    static int mouseY;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                buildFrame();
                runTimer();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void buildFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        label1 = new JLabel("Test1");
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Test Test");
        JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Test Label Label");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        panel.add(label1);
        panel.add(label2);
        panel.add(label3);

        label1.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        label2.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        label3.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setSize(400, 200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void runTimer() {
        inner = new InnerTest();
        t = new Timer(20, inner);
        t.start();
    }

    static class InnerTest implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            mouseX = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x * 100;
            mouseY = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y * 100;
            label1.setText(" ( "+String.valueOf(mouseX)+" , "+String.valueOf(mouseY)+" )");
        }
    }
}
```

How do I keep the components still when another component is updating?

Comment: You may want to use GridBagLayout instead of your BoxLayout. GBL is a little complex, but once you understand it, it is easier to get it to do what you are trying to do here

Comment: Well, the change in position is being caused from the varying length of the text in `label1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The components are added to the same panel so each is centered based on the maximum width of all three components. As the width of the top label changes the others are also adjusted.

The solution is to separate the top label from the other two labels.

One way would be:

```
    //panel.add(label1);
    panel.add(label2);
    panel.add(label3);

    //label1.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    label1.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER); // added
    label2.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    label3.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    frame.add(label1, BorderLayout.PAGE_START); // added
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
```